# Install ansible on windows getting too long

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, cygwin, python-wheel

I am using cygwin64 Terminal to install Ansible on Windows 10. Everything is working find until it get stuck installing pynacl. What am I missing?

```
Collecting ansible
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/01/2c7e45c7eea540c4e4238cd404ccc950c0ef61ebf8d29d04b191caba4fb8/ansible-2.7.9.tar.gz
Collecting jinja2 (from ansible)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/ff/ae64bacdfc95f27a016a7bed8e8686763ba4d277a78ca76f32659220a731/Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyYAML (from ansible)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/2c/9417b5c774792634834e730932745bc09a7d36754ca00acf1ccd1ac2594d/PyYAML-5.1.tar.gz
Collecting paramiko (from ansible)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/ae/94e70d49044ccc234bfdba20114fa947d7ba6eb68a2e452d89b920e62227/paramiko-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible) (40.7.3)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from jinja2->ansible)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/2e/64db92e53b86efccfaea71321f597fa2e1b2bd3853d8ce658568f7a13094/MarkupSafe-1.1.1.tar.gz
Collecting bcrypt>=3.1.3 (from paramiko->ansible)
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from paramiko->ansible)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/7c/c9386b82a25115cccf1903441bba3cbadcfae7b678a20167347fa8ded34c/pyasn1-0.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko->ansible)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/ab/2ac6dea8489fa713e2b4c6c5b549cc962dd4a842b5998d9e80cf8440b7cd/PyNaCl-1.3.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible) (1.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible) (1.0.18)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible) (0.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible) (16.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography->ansible) (2.17)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from packaging->cryptography->ansible) (2.1.10)
Building wheels for collected packages: pynacl
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have win10 Version >= 1709, you could use WSL - Windows Subsystem for Linux. It has a special Linuxkernel within Windows. Within WSL it is very easy to install Ansible. I prefere the way using `pip install ansible`. pip is the python package manager, so after start WSL, you could run:

```
sudo apt update && upgrade
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
sudo pip3 install ansible
```

then you have the newest ansible runing on your windows 10.

Good Luck!

Oliver

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am gonna try your solution but still need an answer to this problem.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/pyca/pynacl/issues/404#issuecomment-429267083.  themiwi said on 12 Oct 2018: Since Cygwin already contains a package for sodium, the trick is to install with the exported SODIUM_INSTALL=system environment variable.

Comment: Hint by @OliverGaida was the solution for me!